# How do i change the id of $(this) element in jquery

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to change the id of an element or of $(this) in jQuery?
At the moment I have tried

```
this.id = 'unlike_comment';
or $(this).attr('id' , 'newid');
```

It is really essential that I can sort this out for my script, there is no other way around then to change the id

Comment: A fiddle will help demo your intent

Comment: `$(this).attr('id' , 'newid');` would change the `id` attribute

Comment: As @zerkms notes, that line of code should change the `id` attribute, is there some reason to believe it is not working? In other words, how are you checking to see if the id has changed or not? Please do use jsfiddle or Stack Snippets to provide [a minimum, clear, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: i am looking via inspect element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish by changing the ID of your element. I would not recommend that you do this but it should work.

```
$("#theDiv").click(function(event){
    $(this).attr("id", "clickedTheDiv");
});
```

ID Removal Fiddle: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/pbk0gg3o/)

If you are wanting to change how the element looks. What I would recommend you change the class via [addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) / [removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) / [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) instead of changing the ID.

Toggle Class:

```
$("#likestatus").click(function(event){
    var inst = $(this);        
    var isLiked = inst.hasClass("liked");        
    inst.toggleClass("liked", !isLiked);
    inst.toggleClass("unliked", isLiked);        
});
```

Toggle Fiddle: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/pbk0gg3o/1/)

Comment: it wasent working because i was trying $(this) inside an ajax call

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).attr("id" , "newid");
```

but the better way:

```
$(this).removeClass("like_comment");
```

the touching id-s is the worst idea.